# How to add a legend to the motion chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use this script that creates a motion chart (see the [original source code](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/) and a simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joseph8691/ja08wyra/1/)). I wonder if it's possible to add the legend to this chart that would show the meaning of each color. The meaning should correspond to the field `name` from the input JSON.

Normally I create a legend as follows:

```
var colors = ["#F0E5FF","#E1CCFF","#C499FF","#AC79F2","#8D4CE5","#6100E5","#C94D8C"];
var colorScaleDomain = [300, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000];

var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                   .domain(colorScaleDomain)
                   .range(colors);
```

However, not sure how to adapt it to my current case when I use `colorScale = d3.scale.category10()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `d3.scale.category10()` operates in a first-come first-served basis, that is, it adds values to the domain as new data comes in, you just need to pass the `name` in the same order that you painted the circles.

However, for this to work, you'll have to change your function `color()`:

```
function color(d) {
    return d.name;
}
```

Now, both the circles and the legends will have the same domain in the color scale.

Now, create the legends:

```
var legendGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(600,50)");

var legend = legendGroup.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(SPX.map(d => d.name))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => "translate(0," + 20 * i + ")")

var legendRects = legend.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("fill", d => colorScale(d));

var legendText = legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 14)
    .attr("y", 8)
    .text(d => d);
```

Here is your fiddle, I put the legends in the top-right corner: http://jsfiddle.net/8yd04e0p/

Comment: Could you please tell me where to see how to make horizontal label. In my case it currently overlaps with the circles.